# How to customize a controllers endpoint path by using config parameter in Odoo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, python-3.7, odoo-15

This is my very first question on stackoverflow.

I am coding an API for something on **Odoo 15**. My module has an endpoint to do stuff. Also the module has settings tab to change some parameters. I want to enable users to change the endpoint path from the settings tab due to some security concerns. Maybe some code helps you understand my problem.

```py
from odoo import http

class MyAPI(http.Controller):
    @http.route("/<I WANT TO MAKE THIS CHANGEABLE>", type="json", auth="public", methods=["POST"])
    def my_response(self, **record):
        ...
```

I know I have to restart the system on every change.

I know how to get config parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could choose the following route `@http.route('/myapi/<string:custom_endpoint>', ...)` and then check whether the configuration parameter equals **custom_endpoint** inside the **my_response** method.

Otherwise, I don't think the route can be dependent on an Odoo configuration parameter, because the @http.route(...) is a decorator and those basically transform the decorated function when the module is imported by Python, which happens before you have access to configuration parameters.